# How to add condition "LIKE ? %something%" to the product title to this join

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

```
Product.find(:all,
    :conditions => { :companies => { :malls => { :id => 1},:products => {:title => "nexus one"} }},
    :joins => [:company => :mall])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I think I have to take break,

```
Product.find(:all,:conditions => ['title LIKE ? and mall_id = ?', "%#{search}%",mall_id],
        :joins => [:company => :mall])
```